# Get the values of the selected rows with checked checkbox

Tags: oracle-apex

Having a report of the services table with checkbox for each row, I am trying to get the values of the selected service, so that when I click on next I can create a report with the services chosen in the new page.

I have tried in this way:

Report of the services table.

```
select code,
        name,
        cost,
        apex_item.hidden(p_idx   => 1, 
            p_value => code) ||
        apex_item.hidden(p_idx   => 2, 
            p_value => cost) ||
        apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx   => 3, 
            p_value => code) CheckBox
from services
```

[image]

I created a process.

Source:

```
begin
    apex_collection.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION ('SDBA_ORDER_ITEMS1');

    for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop
        apex_collection.add_member(
            p_collection_name => 'SDBA_ORDER_ITEMS1',
            p_c001            => to_number(apex_application.g_f01(i)), -- service_code
            p_c002            => to_number(apex_application.g_f02(i)), -- cost
            p_c003            => to_number(apex_application.g_f03(i)) -- service_code
        );
    end loop;
end;
```

Server-side Condition:

```
begin
    for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop
        for j in 1..apex_application.g_f03.count loop
            if apex_application.g_f01(i) = apex_application.g_f03(j) then
                return true;
            else
                return false;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;

Report on the next page.

select (select name from services where code = c001) as service_name,
       c002 as cost
from apex_collections
where collection_name = 'SDBA_ORDER_ITEMS1'
order by 1
```

Report on the next page.

```
select (select name from services where code = c001) as service_name,
       c002 as cost
from apex_collections
where collection_name = 'SDBA_ORDER_ITEMS1'
order by 1
```

In this report it shows all the services of the table instead of the selected ones.

How can I get only the selected rows? Can anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes are formed into dense collections, not potentially sparse like the other item types. I think this is a product of web tech, not APEX.

So if you had ID, Name, Checkbox

```
1 - ada - checked
2 - charles - not checked
3 - alan - checked
```

There would be 3 index elements in ID and Names array, and only 2 in the checkbox array - and index element 3 would be empty.

So you need to match checkbox existence by indexing by the code value, and checking for existence more like

```
apex_application.g_f03(apex_application.g_f01.code)
```

While taking care of potential `no_data_found`

Answer (score 1):

Reading [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/aeapi/Referencing-Values-Within-an-On-Submit-Process.html):

> Note that check boxes displayed using APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX only contain values in the APEX_APPLICATION arrays for those rows which are checked. Unlike other items (TEXT, TEXTAREA, and DATE_POPUP) which can contain an entry in the corresponding APEX_APPLICATION array for every row submitted, a check box only has an entry in the APEX_APPLICATION array if it is selected.

I've build my report referencing rownum on APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX.

Report code:

```sql
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(p_idx => 1, p_value => ROWNUM) checkb
      ,APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(p_idx => 2, p_value => CUSTOMER_ID)||CUSTOMER_ID CUSTOMER_ID
      ,APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(p_idx => 3, p_value => CUST_STATE)||CUST_STATE CUST_STATE
      ,CUST_FIRST_NAME ||' '||CUST_LAST_NAME   
  FROM DEMO_CUSTOMERS
```

And then based on that checked rows, the process is recovering the values in the hidden items arrays corresponding position.

Process PL/SQL code:

```sql
BEGIN  
  --
  FOR i IN 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP      
      --
      INSERT INTO ROMINA_TEST (LOG)
      VALUES ('CUSTOMER_ID: '||APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i))||' - CUST_STATE: '||APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i)));
      --      
  END LOOP;
  --
END;
```

And it works! =)