# Not getting the desired results

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

`enter code here`I have a Problem. Below pl/sql used to be working before and now i dont know whats happening... I want to insert records into a table called incoming from an interactive report using a check box

my sql is

```
SELECT apex_item.checkbox2(1,filenumber)
       || apex_item.hidden(2,filename)   
       || APEX_ITEM.hidden(3,'&APP_USER. ')
       || APEX_ITEM.hidden(4,volume)

       || APEX_ITEM.hidden(6,filename)


       as  "SELECT",

       FILENUMBER,
       FILENAME,
       LOCATION,

       OPENDATE,
       CLOSEDDATE,

       VOLUME,
       SUB,
      temporary,
        registryid,
       STATUS
  from REGISTRY
```

my pl/sql is

```
begin
  for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count
  loop
    if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then
       insert into incoming
         (filenumber,
          filename
         )
         values
         (apex_application.g_f01(idx),
          apex_application.g_f02(idx) 
         );
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

and all this happens after process..this was working fine.. However from recent the problem i am having is the pl/sql gives me the correct filenumber but the incorrect filename.
e.g 
lets say the ir report  has

```
filenumber     filename   
1                 aaron
2                 kerron
3                 Joshua
```

when i select number 2 (second record) the result in the incoming table will be

```
filenumber     filename
      2         aaron
```

its always selecting the first record once it falls in the  apex_item.hidden.

if i reverse it and put

```
SELECT apex_item.checkbox2(1,filename)
       || apex_item.hidden(2,filenumber)
```

the filename is correct and the file number will do what i explained above which is if i choose the second record i will get

```
 filenumber     filename
     1            kerron
```

when i add

```
 begin
      for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count loop

            for i in 1..apex_application.g_f02.count loop

        if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then
           insert into INCOMINGREQUESTNOTIFICATION
             (requestedfile,filenumber


             )
             values
             (apex_application.g_f01(idx),
              apex_application.g_f02(i)




             );
        end if;
      end loop;
    end loop;
    end;
```

@romeuBraga i am getting all 3 rows not the selected one can you tell me what am doing wrong

Comment: Check boxes displayed using APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX will only contain values in the APEX_APPLICATION arrays for those rows which are checked. Because of that, you need two loops. Check in this question how idx items 1 and 3 are used (just in the section "Server-side Condition:"). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463520/get-the-values-of-the-selected-rows-with-checked-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a hidden item to store the ID.
*1 and 2 store the same information

```
select  column1,
        column2,
        column3,
        apex_item.hidden(p_idx   => 1, 
            p_value => code) ||
        apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx   => 2, 
            p_value => code) CheckBox,
        other items
from x
```

in this case, you need this pl/sql to get the correct row values.

```
begin
    for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop
        for j in 1..apex_application.g_f02.count loop
            if apex_application.g_f01(i) = apex_application.g_f02(j) then
                --insert something here
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
```