# Oracle Apex Apex_application.G_fNN processing not pulling all the values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm very much new to oracle apex and have been constantly failing on creating tabular form for inserting data into my table. My scenario is as follows.

i have two tables
1. tasks(task_id, task_Name)
2. Efforts (Eff_id,Task_id,Hours_spent,NOtes).

I want to create a tabular form to insert data into Efforts table with the tasks that I've in Tasks table. I created the tabular form with the query below.

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,TASK_ID) "TASK_ID",
       TASK_NAME,
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(2,'')"HOURS_SPENT",
       APEX_ITEM.TEXT(3,'')"NOTES"
FROM TASKS;
```

but when I create the "after Submit" process to read the values of this report and tried to insert into my table effortS with the following code, something strange is happening. When i select the checkbox of row-1,2 and 3 then only row 1 is getting inserted into my efforts table but for the rest, only task id values are getting inserted not the whole row. I was missing "hours_spent and NOtes". in my efforts table for rows-2 and 3..here is my plsql block

```
BEGIN
FOR i in APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
INSERT INTO EFFORTS(EFF_ID,TASK_ID,HOURS_SPENT,NOTES)
VALUES (SEQ_EFFORTS.NEXTVAL,APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i),APEX_APPLICATION.G_F02(i),APEX_APPLICATION.G_F03(i))
END LOOP;
commit;
END;
```

Can Someone help me! if there's another way of doing my requirement, then I'm more than happy to do it..

Comment: Whenever possible, I would suggest using Interactive grids. They can do most of the same things Tabular forms do, but a whole lot better. APEX_ITEM is the stuff of nightmares for me, I spent multiple weeks fiddling with it and htp.p, If I could have done it in Interactive grids I would have in in instant, but sadly I needed something that could not be done, so please, try using Interactive grids, save yourself the torture.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the APEX community.

This is a classic problem, due to the nature of HTML

[Get the values of the selected rows with checked checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463520/get-the-values-of-the-selected-rows-with-checked-checkbox)

Note, the usage of tabular forms is also waning in favour of [Interactive Grids](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r51/building_and_customizing_interactive_grid/interactive_grids_part1.html).